# Connect aws postgres db to the vercel

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, vercel

i'm trying to connect to vercel with aws postgres db  
I've created an instance of free tier rds
and i got endpoint  
so  this  is  my server code

```
 const connection = await createConnection({
type: 'postgres',
url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
logging: false,
synchronize: false,

entities: [
  User,
],
});
```

so my main question is  how to create url

I've tried  DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:password@my aws endpoint:5432/my aws database name 
and not worked  vercel error said 
ERROR : Task timed out after 10.01 seconds 
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the aws rds db instance, down on the right ( once you select the instance) there will be vpc security groups select it and add inbound and outbound firewall rules for the ip you are connecting with, if its your local it will be your wan ip. You can also test it with allow all traffic but I would strongly suggest against it.

Answer (score 0):

`Task timed out` is almost always due to wrong or missing firewall rules. Verify that the RDS instance security group(s) has a rule for the vercel server.